# SQL Azure deployment security concerns

Tags: sql, security, azure

We are developing an application that uses a Windows Azure cloud service, and a SQL Azure database. We have an ASP .NET MVC project that uses database-first to create the entities in our Visual Studio solution. Now we need to deploy the database schema to Azure.

Currently this is not possible because our network blocks outbound access on port 1433, which is the only port SQL Azure is available on. We have asked our security team for permission to open port 1433 outbound, but they have some concerns:

1. There is unencrypted database traffic (port 1433) allowed at Microsoft's firewall over the internet for Azure. Although there is no sensitive information in the database, management credentials are probably in clear text if database credentials are not encrypted and can lead to defacement risks.
2. What network ports are opened at the internet firewall for access to the system hosting the website and database?

I believe the concern in the first question is that credentials for managing the Azure DB will be sent over on port 1433 unencrypted during deployment. For the second one, I think the answer is that we can configure endpoints to open whatever ports we want for our cloud service, but they are closed by default.

I did some research, but was unable to find any definitive answers on these questions from Microsoft, which makes me think we are asking the wrong questions. I would be interested in insight from anyone with more experience in this than I have.

Comment: You can also perform some of your db setup over https via the silverlight plugin launched from the azure management portal

Comment: You are very wrong with your first assumption. SQL Azure requires explicit encryption. Meaning that it will refuse any unencrypted connections! You have to read "Security Guidelines and Limitations on Windows Azure SQL Database (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394108.aspx)" before assuming!

Comment: @astaykov Thanks for the link, I had actually read that article but was still unclear on whether the connections over 1433 were encrypted during deployment from Visual Studio to SQL Azure. According to the article: "All communications between Windows Azure SQL Database and your application require encryption (SSL) at all times." Our security department is concerned about communication between SQL Azure and VS, not our application. Also, for the record, our security dept. were the ones making the assumptions, I'm just looking for the right answer :). I appreciate your insight!

Comment: Visual Studio is also "your application". SQL Server Management Studio is also "your application". The code you write is also "your application". SQL Azure will simply reject **any** connection attempt which is not encrypted. Make your "security dept." read the doc carefully, and perform tests if they want. It is extremely easy to detect whether given connection is encrypted or not, if one is real expert in security...

Comment: That was the point that wasn't clear to us from the document. I did do the test, and verified that every connection from our side is encrypted, and communicated that to our security department. Thanks again for your insight!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Azure only accepts encrypted (SSL) communication per the Security Guidelines and Limitations (Windows Azure SQL Database) article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394108.aspx

> Encryption and Certificate Validation All communications between
>   Windows Azure SQL Database and your application require encryption
>   (SSL) at all times. If your client application does not validate
>   certificates upon connection, your connection to Windows Azure SQL
>   Database is susceptible to "man in the middle" attacks.  To validate
>   certificates with application code or tools, explicitly request an
>   encrypted connection and do not trust the server certificates. If your
>   application code or tools do not request an encrypted connection, they
>   will still receive encrypted connections. However, they may not
>   validate the server certificates and thus will be susceptible to "man
>   in the middle" attacks. To validate certificates with ADO.NET
>   application code, set Encrypt=True and TrustServerCertificate=False in
>   the database connection string. For more information, see How to:
>   Connect to Windows Azure SQL Database Using ADO.NET. SQL Server
>   Management Studio also supports certificate validation. In the Connect
>   to Server dialog box, click Encrypt connection on the Connection
>   Properties tab.  SQL Server Management Studio does not support Windows
>   Azure SQL Database in versions prior to SQL Server 2008 R2.

SQL Azure uses 1433 and 8443. The port requirements for Azure are available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj136814.aspx

If you want to limit firewall traffic to and from specific IP addresses, the Azure datacenter IP ranges are available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn175718.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some options (in addition to DarrelNorton's answer):
- you can use a dedicated SQL Server VM, then you can use port forwarding and the port issue is not a problem and you have additional firewall options and additional security software you can instal
- dedicated SQL VM allows you to take advantage of TDE (Trans. Data Encryption) in SQL Server or you can do more advanced encryption techniques that are not available in SQL Azure DB
- Dedicated SQL VM you are isolated from other MSFT clients.  If you get hacked, you can re provision the VM from scripts
- you can use a Virtual Network connection between the MSFT data center and your local network if you are concerned about security (the VPN is encrypted)